# jQuery - How to access "this.options" dataSousrce attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to access `dataSource` attribute of `this.options` how we can access.

I used `console.log(this.options)` which gives me below

```
Object {swfSrcPath: undefined, product: "v3", insertMode: "replace", safeMode: true, overlayButton: undefined…}{
    autoInstallRedirect: false
    chartType: undefined
    containerBackgroundColor: "#ffffff"
    containerElement: div#impact-report-user-filter.context
    containerElementId: "impact-report-user-filter"
    dataConfiguration: undefined
    dataFormat: "xml"


    dataSource: 
       <chart caption='Filter By' labelDisplay='AUTO' useEllipsesWhenOverflow='1' subcaption='' xAxisName='Compliance' yAxisName='Impact of Failure' bgColor='FFAAAA,FFFFFF' exportEnabled='1' exportAtClient='1' exportHandler='fcExporter1' showLabels='0' showValues='0' showLegend='1' legendBorderAlpha='0' legendBgAlpha='0' legendShadow='0' formatNumberScale='0'>
          <set label='Mumbai' value='1' displayValue='Mumbai' link='url'/>
          <set label='Bangalore' value='1' displayValue='Bangalore' link='url'/>
       </chart>

    insertMode: "replace"
    overlayButton: undefined
    product: "v3"
    renderer: "flash"
    safeMode: true
    showDataLoadingMessage: true
    swfSrcPath: undefined
    useLegacyXMLTransport: false
    __proto__: Object
}
```

In that we have a attribute `dataSource` in that **I want to Access each label attribute's value of set tag**. Please help to access `Mumbai`,`Bangalore` and `available all set tag label`

Comment: could you post respective html markup as well

Comment: It is a fusion chart object. with this dataSource it just create fusion chart

Comment: you can fetch the datasource object like like this `console.log(this.options[1].dataSource)`. this would print complete markup as it is, which needs to be parsed to fetch the `displayValue`

Comment: ya, I tried this but not working `var text = this.options.dataSource
   var xml = $.parseXML(text);
            console.log($(xml).find('set').text())`

Comment: $.parseXML is not a function getting this error

Comment: `$.parseXML()` is a jquery defined function, have you included jquery lib in your script ?

Comment: yes I have lots of jquery function running so I don't think inclusion of lib is iisue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105870/discussion-between-dreamweiver-and-soham-shetty).

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch `dataSource` and parse the xml using `$.parseXML()`.
Since there are multiple `set` xmls objects you need to loop through those objects using `$.each()`.

**JS CODE:**

```
var parsedXml = $.parseXML(xmlr);
var sets = $(parsedXml).find('set');
$(sets).each(function() {
   console.log($(this).attr('label'));
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/03fcjc3e/1/)